# Android studio retrieve data from Firebase and get error E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android

I get an error **E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout** when I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase and display by using recyclerView.

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npbVo.png)

[InformationAdapter.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDBBd.png)

[InforamtionModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe18x.png)

Comment: post your code instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these lines:

```
adapter = new InformationAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

above

`FetchData();`